# How do I solve $\oint\limits_C\frac{(x+y)\;\mathrm{d}x-(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y}{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

Here's the following integral:

$$\oint\limits_C\frac{(x+y)\;\mathrm{d}x-(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y}{x^2+y^2}$$

$C$ is given by $x^2+y^2=a^2$

Actually I do not know how to approach it, I tried to parametrize it but it did not work properly, I have no more ideas.

Comment: So $x^2+y^2$ is constant??

Comment: $x=acost$, $y=asint$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you parametrise as $x=a\cos \theta$ and $y=a\sin \theta$, then your integral reduces to
$$ \frac{a^2}{a^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \left((\cos \theta +\sin \theta)(-\sin \theta) -(\cos \theta-\sin \theta)(\cos \theta)\right)d\theta$$
$$=-\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta\right)d\theta$$
$$=-2\pi$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Aha, seems I just took wrong parametrization first.